# Separation of infinite convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If we have two convergent infinite series, such as $S_1 = \sum\limits_n \frac{a_n}{2^n}$ and $S_2 =\sum\limits_n \frac{b_n}{2^n}$, with $a_n, b_n\in \{0,1\}$, then is it true that

$$\left|\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n}{2^n}-\sum\limits_n \frac{b_n}{2^n}\right|=\left|\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n-b_n}{2^n}\right|\le \sum\limits_n\left| \frac{a_n-b_n}{2^n}\right| ?$$

My principal question here is whether or not we can join or separate convergent series like I did above.

Comment: Yes, you can. If $\sum c_n$ and $\sum d_n$ are convergent, then $\sum(c_n + d_n) = \sum c_n + \sum d_n$, as you can check in a moment reasoning on the partial sums.

Comment: sequence: and if Rigel's comment is not obvious to you, take some time to do it yourself!